# In Cocoa View Hierarchy what determines the subView position?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa /objective-C coming from Java/C# and C/C++ . Cocoa has been giving me lots of headaches. I have read an apple's article on View hierarchy in cocoa. But still confusions.

I need to know when I add a subView to a view programatically not via interface builder. Where exactly will the view be placed relative to other subviews assuming there are other subviews in the same parent view.

In java there are layout managers, in C# there is also vertical/horizontal panel etc, so we know if I add an item/control it will be going to the right of the existing item or to the bottom of it.

So if I do as shown in the following line what exactly determines where the new subview will be placed ??

```
    [[window contentView] addSubview:newView];
```

Thanks,

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html

Comment: That really doesn't seem to be relevant, @iPatel. This is specifically about how the `NSView` class positions subviews, not about design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The frame of the view defines the rect that it occupies in its superview's coordinates, so its position will be `frame.origin`. That can be set either before or after you add the subview.

This is spelled out fairly clearly in the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW2).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are using Autolayout or not.

If you are not, then when you create a view you call -[NSView initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame] and that frame will will define where the view appears in the superview's coordinates.

```
_view = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (50, 50, 100, 50)];
```

will make an NSTextField size 100x50 and it will be placed 50,50 pixels inside the superview.

If you are using Autolayout, then the position of a view depend entirely on what layout constraints apply to it. With Autolayout any frame that you set will be ignored. While autolayout has a steep learning curve, once you set your constraints, it (in theory) means you can ignore the layout.

Answer (score 1):

The `frame` rectangle gives the view's size and position in the superview. The frame is at position 0,0 (x,y) with a size of 0,0 (w,h) by default. The position in the subview collection is entirely ignored except in rare cases like NSSplitView.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa doesn't automatically align any views. There is no initial layout mechanism like in .net or java.
You have to position all your views manually by setting their frames in points.
By default, the origin of a fresh initialized view is at (0,0).

Comment: I don't know .NET, but there is indeed an autolayout mechanism in Cocoa: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1

Comment: That's something different. Autolayout in cocoa can handles layouts **after** you set an initial frame. It doesn't automagically align your views just by using it.

Comment: Auto layout doesn't use the frames and when using autolayout you shouldnt be setting frames. You can call initWithFrame:NSZeroRect and it will lay it out appropriately using the specified constraints.

Comment: Exactly, but you have to do it yourself by setting the initial constraints. It still doesn't do any layout magically by itself like e.g. a table or collection view.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the documentation and header file don't specify exactly the origin (x,y) the added subview will be placed. What I do after add a subview is to calculate a new origin (and if applicable) size before repositioning the subview using CGRectMake().